# Efficient Form layout in html

Tags: html, css

Im in the process of converting a silverlight application to a "html5" web application. Im just wanting to know what is the most efficient/readable manor to layout a complex enterprise form. Here is an example of a form:

[image]

I could lay this out in xaml in a few minutes. It would be laid out as follows:

[image]

I've heard its bad form to use tables in html. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The [CSS3 Flexible Box](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/) model is most likely what you want… However, support for it is very, very poor at the moment, especially because the old flexbox standard was changed dramatically quite recently.

Comment: @Raven hey i thing you want to this http://tinkerbin.com/YZuf83MX

Comment: @RohitAzad that is pretty well spot on exactly what I want. Only problem I can see is, why doesnt the first width_Auto column expand dynamically like the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Object-Oriented CSS that will solve the layout issue automatically. you will want to fit the structure to different sizes in different scenarios so you might want to use a grid system in your css to centralize the design layout.

```
.left { float:left; }
.right { float: right }
.global { width: 960px; }
.onefifth { width: 20%; }
.onetenth { width: 10%; }
.onetwentieth { width: 5%; }
```

and so on...

I promise you this approach will reduce your styling by a lot resulting in higher performance.

IMHO not using tables makes life easier.

see: https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/ (object-oriented CSS)
This is what Nicole Sullivan did with Yahoo and Facebook, it is definitely worth looking at

Answer (score 1):

Some may argue that a form is indeed tabular data, or at least input of tabular data.
Instead of using a table like:

```
Name      | John 
Last Name | Doe
Country   | XX
```

You could say that:

```
Name      | <input>
Last Name | <input>
Country   | <input>
```

could also work like a table, so I think it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you REALLY need html5 or just heard it's modern?

Secondly, tables are bad if you don't use them for tabular data. For instance it's a very bad thing to layout a website by using tables. For your scenario I'd suggest to learn about css a bit and utilize some floating, divs, fieldsets etc.

Comment: no the website really isnt html5 its just a asp.net mvc page. Just quoting the buzz word.

Comment: @Raven, ehm, a website can be asp.net mvc and html5 at the same time, those are not mutually exclusive :) Asp.net MVC is a "server-side-thingy", while html5 is the actual html version that's being passed to the client browser.

Comment: mate we're digressing from the point at hand. I know what html5 is (and really its a stupid term that is so broad it doesnt even make sense anymore, i was just referencing it as a buzz word in the topic question). The question here really doesnt relate to html5 or asp.net mvc. It relates to html and css.